# Restricting second date to + days in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

**This was marked as duplicate earlier and i did not get any answers. It's not a duplicate so please don't mark it as such**, The other post was related to restrict second date to currently selected date in the first pick, i'm not trying to do that, already have that. I'm trying to add +3days to the second calendar/date. So if i select today on the first date and the on the second date i should not be able to select dates from that date + 3 days.

**Example**: From date is 21/12/2016 then in the second field i can not select earlier date then 24/12/2016.

I'm having issues with date-range in my datepicker. I need to have the "carrental_to_date" with minimum 3 days after the selected "carrental_from_date" but nothing seems to work.

I have tried changing the "minDate" on the "to_date" to "+3d" but it not seems to pick that up, i did find one example of this here: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/dxbtp/494/ but i'm not able to get that working either. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here and was hoping one of you geniuses was able to point me in the right direction.

```
jQuery('#carrental_from_date' + element_id).datepicker({
            //showOn: "both",
            beforeShow: carrental_customRange,
            dateFormat: "<?php echo date_format_js(isset($theme_options['date_format']) ? $theme_options['date_format'] : ''); ?>",
            firstDay: "<?php echo (isset($theme_options['date_format_first_day']) ? (int) $theme_options['date_format_first_day'] : 0); ?>",
            dayNamesMin: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Su') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Mo') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Th') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Fr') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Sa') ?>"],
            monthNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('January') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('February') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('March') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('April') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('May') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('June') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('July') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('August') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('September') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('October') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('November') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('December') ?>"],
            dayNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Sunday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Monday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tuesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wednesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Thursday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Friday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Saturday') ?>"],
            nextText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Next') ?>",
            prevText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Prev') ?>",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function() {
                carrental_update_business_hours(element_id);
            }
        });

        jQuery('#carrental_to_date' + element_id).datepicker({
            //showOn: "both",
            beforeShow: carrental_customRange,
            dateFormat: "<?php echo date_format_js(isset($theme_options['date_format']) ? $theme_options['date_format'] : ''); ?>",
            firstDay: "<?php echo (isset($theme_options['date_format_first_day']) ? (int) $theme_options['date_format_first_day'] : 0); ?>",
            dayNamesMin: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Su') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Mo') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wu') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Th') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Fr') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Sa') ?>"],
            monthNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('January') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('February') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('March') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('April') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('May') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('June') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('July') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('August') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('September') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('October') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('November') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('December') ?>"],
            dayNames: ["<?php echo CarRental::t('Sunday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Monday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Tuesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Wednesday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Thursday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Friday') ?>", "<?php echo CarRental::t('Saturday') ?>"],
            nextText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Next') ?>",
            prevText: "<?php echo CarRental::t('Prev') ?>",
            minDate: 0,
            onSelect: function() {
                carrental_update_business_hours(element_id);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

From the API for `minDate`:

> The minimum selectable date. When set to null, there is no minimum.
>   Multiple types supported:
>
> **Date:** A date object containing the minimum date.
>
> **Number:** A number of days from today. For example 2 represents two days from today and -1 represents yesterday.
>
> **String:** A string in the format defined by the dateFormat option, or a relative date. Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are "y" for years, "m" for months, "w" for weeks, and "d" for days. For example, "+1m +7d" represents one month and seven days from today.

I would advise the String method: `+3d`. When a date is selected in the From field, you can set that value as the date for the To field.

Working Example from you example: http://jsfiddle.net/dxbtp/871/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("setDate", selected);
      $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", "+3d");
    }
  });

  $("#txtToDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("setDate", selected);
      $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", "-3d")
    }
  });
});
```